# Button inside Cell Table View Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom cell with a button.
 
When I implement the outlet get me a error.

This is a screen :

[image]

Comment: Paste both your code and the error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add the IBOutlet to the view controller instead of inside the cell.. You need a UITableViewCell class and add there the IBOutlet. I also recommend you to use a verbe for the IBActions method names.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, if you didn't create a custom UITableViewCell class.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JG_AMY_gSDQ

Comment: Doesn't contain a button...  but nice tutorial